# Invalid multibyte character for locale when attempting to create Trigrams index

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using the [musicbrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/) database through PostgresSQL in Windows 10. I used [these](https://bitbucket.org/lalinsky/mbslave) scripts in order to import it to my own computer (this might be irrelevant). The encoding of the data is UTF-8.

Today I tried to create some indexes using Trigrams in order to improve the speed of my string-based searches, and this error appeared when I was creating the first one:

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx_release_group_name ON release_group USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);

ERROR:  invalid multibyte character for locale
HINT:  The server's LC_CTYPE locale is probably incompatible with the
database encoding.
SQL state: 22021
```

The LC_CTYPE is `Spanish_Spain.1252`, which, seems to be the issue as it is not UTF-8.

The solution then is to create my DB with a locale compatible with UTF-8 but I cannot find that locale, as the names are different from the Linux locales. I have tried creating the database from the pgAdmin but in locale list I only find `C`, `POSIX` and `Spanish_Spain.1252`. I tried creating it with `createdb` like this:

`createdb -U palp example-db -l=Spanish_Spain`

but got the same locale as before with the -l argument as a comment. (I tried the command with different values of the locale and different quotation marks but got the same result).

Am I doing this wrong? Is the locale name wrong and thus, that is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: That might be a Windows-specific PostgreSQL bug.

Comment: Yes, that might be the case but I prefer to think that there is an easy way to solve it and just that I don't know how to do it. I have looked around on the internet and found nothing, do you suggest anything?

Comment: One workaround would be to create the database with encoding `WIN1252`, but then you are limited in your choice of characters.